# How do I add a new attribute to a migration in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

Here's my story: I had something like this set up a while ago.

```
  create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.database_authenticatable :null => false
  t.recoverable
  t.rememberable
  t.trackable

  t.integer :total_pageviews
```

and "total_pageviews" worked fine. I could set it to zero, increment it, multiply it, call it, whatever. but let's say i want to add:

```
  t.integer :total_votes
```

What do I have to do to configure total_votes as an attribute? Whenever I try to use "total_votes", I get undefined method error. I'm thinking that the answer is something like rake `db:migrate` or similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not ever alter existing migrations. If you have checked them in to your version control system and somebody else runs them and then you add a new field to them and commit that change, they will not know to get that change. Then you must tell them and it's a pain in the butt to fix.

If you've not committed it yet then rollback the migration (`rake db:rollback`), make the necessary modification and re-run it again (`rake db:migrate`).

But in the Real World, you would create a *new* migration which adds this field using `rails g migration add_total_votes_to_users total_votes:integer`.

Rails will interpret this migration name and know what to do with it, generating a migration that contains this line:

```
add_column :users, :total_votes, :integer
```

Then when you run this migration it will add this `total_votes` field to the `users` table which will make an attribute of the same name for all `User` objects.

Comment: thanks, looking back now I see that I had a bunch of add_(attribute)_to_(table) migrations in here. but sometimes, when I edit the create migration file, it works. what gives? do you know the answer? thanks in advance

Comment: Just for future visitor's sakes: If you edit the migration file *before* you run it then it will still be runnable. Otherwise you will need to roll it back and then migrate forward again.

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding this after the migration has been run? So, the users table exists and you want to add a column to it? If so, you need go create a migration like

```
rails generate migration add_total_votes_to_users
```

Open it up (just to verify that the table and column are correct). Then run the migration.

Answer (score 1):

If you app is in production, then you should create a new migration. If you app is in pre-production stage, and you have a small development team with good communication, then I recommend you to go ahead and modify the migration and then do

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

then you can commit the modified migration file and **let the rest of you team know that that you have changed a migration file**.